# How to create a virtual host for a Tornado HTTP server

Tags: python, tornado, virtualhost

I want to redirect a random local domain i.e. http://mypage.local to http://localhost/:8888 where I am running a tornado HTTP server that delivers the website. I got all the information from the official docs [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application). Code see below (main.py).

I also added the following line to my /etc/vhosts file:

```
127.0.0.1:8888       mypage.local
```

But trying to open http://mysite.local results in a classical "Page not found" error. What do I do wrong?

**main.py:**

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application, url

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("<p>Hello, world</p><p><a href='/story/5'>Go to story 5</a></p>")

class StoryHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, story_id):
        self.write("this is story %s" % story_id)

def make_app():
    return Application([
        url(r"/", MainHandler),
        url(r"/story/([0-9]+)", StoryHandler)  
    ])

def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.add_handlers(r"mypage.local", [
        (r"/story/([0-9]+)", StoryHandler),
    ])    
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit /etc/hosts file, but it doesn't support port forwarding. So you can write:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.local
```

And access your server by http://mysite.local:8888

You can run tornado on 80 port as root, but it would be better to use nginx to forward requests to tornado:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.local;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to access my site by http://mypage.local, without explicitely writing the port? Is there any way of automatic redirection?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html)

```
application = web.Application([
    (HostMatches("example.com"), [
        (r"/", MainPageHandler),
        (r"/feed", FeedHandler),
    ]),
])
```

Can be use like this

```
application = web.Application([
    (HostMatches("localhost"), [
        (r"/", Admin_Handler)
    ]),

    (HostMatches("website1.com"), [
        (r"/", Site_1_Handler),
        (r"/feed", Site_1_FeedHandler),
    ]),

    (HostMatches("website2.com"), [
        (r"/", Site_2_Handler),
        (r"/feed", Site_2_FeedHandler),
    ]),

    (HostMatches("(.*)"), [
        (r"/", Main_Handler),
        (r"/feed", Main_FeedHandler),
    ]),
])
```